# Manipulating JSON in Go ReST service that uses Gorilla

Tags: json, rest, go

I have a Go ReST service that receives JSON, and I need to edit the JSON so I may make two different structs.

My structs:

```
type Interaction struct{

 DrugName string `json:"drugName"`
 SeverityLevel string `json:"severityLevel"`
 Summary string `json:"summary"`
}

type Drug struct {
 Name string `json:"drugName"`
 Dosages []string `json:"dosages"`
 Interactions []Interaction `json:"interactions"`
}
```

Example JSON being sent:

```
{"drugName":"foo","dosages":["dos1"],"interactions":[["advil","high","summaryForAdvil"]]}
```

The ReST service:

```
func CreateDrug(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  //I verified the received JSON by printing out the bytes:
  bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
}
```

My goal is the make two different JSONs in the CreateDrug function so I may make the two different structs, Drug and Interaction:

```
{"drugName":"foo","dosages":["dos1"]}
{"drugName":"advil", "severityLevel":"high", "summary":"summaryForAdvil"}
```

In Go, in this function, how do I use the received JSON to make two new JSONs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmarshal the request to a struct matching the structure of the request, copy values to the structs you have defined, and marshal to create the result.

```
func CreateDrug(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  // Unmarshal request to value matching the structure of the incoming JSON

  var v struct {
    DrugName     string
    Dosages      []string
    Interactions [][3]string
  }
  if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&v); err != nil {
    // handle error
  }

  // Copy to new struct values.

  var interactions []Interaction
  for _, i := range v.Interactions {
    interactions = append(interactions, Interaction{DrugName: i[0], SeverityLevel: i[1], Summary: i[2]})
  }

  drug := &Drug{Name: v.DrugName, Dosages: v.Dosages, Interactions: interactions}

  // Marshal back to JSON.

  data, err := json.Marshal(drug)
  if err != nil {
      // handle error
  }

  // Do something with data.
}
```

<kbd>[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/vVQ6VrkW2A)</kbd>

(I am assuming that you want a single JSON value for Drug with the Interactions field filled in. If that's not what you want, marshal the Drug and Interactions values separately.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.Encoder` and output multiple json structs to a stream, you just have to decode the input json, here's a simple example:

```
type restValue struct {
    Name         string      `json:"drugName"`
    Dosages      []string    `json:"dosages"`
    Interactions [][3]string `json:"interactions"`
}

func main() {
    d := []byte(`{"drugName":"foo","dosages":["dos1"],"interactions":[["advil","high","summaryForAdvil"]]}`)
    var v restValue
    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &v); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    interactions := make([]Interaction, 0, len(v.Interactions))
    for _, in := range v.Interactions {
        interactions = append(interactions, Interaction{in[0], in[1], in[2]})
    }
    drug := &Drug{Name: v.Name, Dosages: v.Dosages, Interactions: interactions}
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    // if you want the whole Drug struct
    enc.Encode(drug)

    // or if you want 2 different ones:
    drug = &Drug{Name: v.Name, Dosages: v.Dosages}
    enc.Encode(drug)
    for _, in := range interactions {
        enc.Encode(in)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Ccv8S1Pe2M)

Comment: this looks great, i don't know if i can test now or not, but i'll get to it for sure in a while. i'll accept the first answer, for i just tested it. thx for the help